# How can I remove a package from Laravel using PHP Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, uninstallation, package-managers

What is the correct way to remove a package from Laravel using PHP Composer?

So far I've tried:

1. Remove declaration from file *composer.json* (in the "require" section)
2. Remove any *class aliases* from file *app.php*
3. Remove any references to the package from my code :-)
4. Run `composer update`
5. Run `composer dump-autoload`

None of these options are working! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1089, accepted):

### Composer 1.x and 2.x

Running the following command will remove the package from vendor (or wherever you install packages), *composer.json* and *composer.lock*. Change vendor/package appropriately.

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

Obviously you'll need to remove references to that package within your app.

I'm currently running the following version of Composer:

```
Composer version 1.0-dev (7b13507dd4d3b93578af7d83fbf8be0ca686f4b5) 2014-12-11 21:52:29
```

### Documentation

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#remove-rm

#### Updates

- 27/12/2023 - Fixed URL to `remove-rm` documentation
- 26/10/2020 - Updated answer to assert command works for v1.x and v2.x of Composer

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak composer update will update all dependencies. It way leave the project in unstable state. Don't use composer update unless you want to update dependencies

Comment: `composer remove packagename` , It updates removing package from composer.json and removes package folder from vendor... laravel - 5.4.24, composer - 1.4.2.

Comment: It seems like composer is automatically installing missing packages after running `composer remove <package>`. Anyway to avoid that? Using version 1.7.2.

Comment: it should be: composer remove package_name
instead: composer remove vendor/package
there is no need of vendor as laravel automatically check in vendor directory for packages.

Comment: If you don't want your packages to be updated after removing a module you can run `composer install` instead of `composer update`

Comment: @prashant `vendor` here is also a variable. For example, if you were removing Carbon, you would run `composer remove nesbot/carbon`. In this example, `nesbot` is the name of the vendor.

Comment: composer2 tells me "xy in your composer is not required and thus not removed"... well, can't i force composer to purge it

Answer (score 216):

I got it working... The steps to remove a package from Laravel are:

1. Remove the declaration from file *composer.json* (in the "require" section)
2. **Remove Service Provider from file *config/app.php* (reference in the "providers" array)
3. Remove any class aliases from file *config/app.php*
4. Remove any references to the package from your code :-)
5. Run `composer update vendor/package-name`. This will remove the package folder from the `vendor` folder and will rebuild the Composer autoloading map.
6. Manually delete the published files (read [the comment by zwacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer#comment35357408_23126884))

It will remove the package folder from the `Vendor` folder.

Comment: although unpublishing assets/configs isn't really an automated thing. i usually delete manually the vendor/package folders in config/ or public/.

Comment: now laravel should come up with something like "remove package <package-name>" to make it easier.

Comment: A problem with this solution is that it will update all other packages, which may not be what you want.

Comment: (1) and (5) can be replaced with running `composer remove vendor/package`, I think.

Answer (score 63):

Normally `composer remove` used like this is enough:

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

But if a Composer package is removed and the "config" cache is not cleaned you cannot clean it. When you try like so

```
php artisan config:clear
```

you can get an error `In ProviderRepository.php line 208:`

> Class 'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider' not found

This is a dead end, unless you go deleting files:

Laravel 5.6

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Laravel 9

```
rm bootstrap/cache/packages.php
```

It happens usually on automated deployment, when you copy files of a new release on top of old cache. Even if you cleared the cache before copying. You end up with an old cache and a new *composer.json* file.

Comment: With 5.6, my bootstrap/cache was empty. I forgot that I'd changed the cache path (config/cache.php)! Deleting the files in the new cache folder fixed the problem!

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev This is not fixed Even in 5.7

Comment: I almost spent 3 hours pulling my hairs out over this.
I thought `config:clear` would fix this.

Answer (score 40):

You can remove any package just by typing the following command in the terminal, and just remove the providers and alias you provided at the time of installing the package, if any and update the composer,

```
composer remove vendor/your_package_name
composer update
```

Comment: Sometimes to update the new dependancies, you have to update the composer. I think there is no harm in running that.

Answer (score 22):

Before removing a package from a *composer.json* declaration, please remove the cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear  
php artisan config:clear
```

If you forget to remove the cache and you get a *"class not found error"* then please reinstall the package, clear the cache and remove again.

Answer (score 22):

Running

```
composer remove package/name
php artisan optimize:clear
```

e.g "Composer remove mckenziearts/laravel-notify" works for me while using Laravel 8.

Answer (score 21):

You can do any one of the below two methods:

1. Running the below command (most recommended way to remove your package without updating your other packages)

   `$ composer remove vendor/package`
2. Go to your composer.json file and then run command like below it will remove your package (but it will also update your other packages)

   `$ composer update`

Answer (score 17):

If you are still getting the error after you are done with all the steps in the previous answers, go to your projects, *Bootstrap* → *Cache* → *config.php*. Remove the provider and aliases entries from the cached array manually.

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: Some package vendor does not meet all requirements to create a package. For that reason, these vendors `composer remove vendor/package` unable to remove the cache entries properly. So, @Ramjith Ap is absolutely correct here.

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
composer remove vendor/package
```

This is an example:

#### Install or add a package

```
composer require firebear/importexportfree
```

#### Uninstall / remove

```
composer remove firebear/importexportfree
```

Finally after removing:

```
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy –f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php -f bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 14):

To add the packages, the command is to be like:

```
composer require spatie/laravel-permission
```

To remove the packages, the command is to be like:

```
composer remove spatie/laravel-permission
```

Comment: Omg, I was looking for composer remove command to remove exactly this package.

Answer (score 9):

In case the given answers still don't help you remove that, try this:

- Manually delete the line in `require` from `composer.json`
- Run `composer update`

Answer (score 6):

If this doesn't work "composer remove package/name", you can still remove it manually. 
Note : package/name is like spatie etc.

1. Go to composer.json and find the package name
2. Delete package name from composer.json
3. Find the vendor file in your Laravel project.
4. Delete the package file which is under vendor
5. run `composer install` on your terminal

Note : Package File mean is that package that you are looking for. For example, you want to remove Spatie. Then you need to find that with similar name in vendor file and you need to delete it manually. 
Your package was removed successfully.

Comment: What is that "package file"? Do you mean `composer.lock`? You forgot to add the consequences that deleting the lock file cuases, like updating other dependencies

Comment: For example, you have a package named as spatie. You will find it under vendor file. composer.json. All installed package will be starage under Vendor with package's name.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove Spatie"? That's not a package. Also, `composer remove` does all this automatically

Comment: Spatie is an example package name. It's a permission management package for Laravel. I just gave it as an example. @NicoHaase
Sometimes composer remove doesn't work and we need to remove it manually. It's another solution to this problem.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 5):

You have two solution.

**First**

Use `remove` of `composer`.

```
composer remove *your_package_name*
```

**Second**

Delete the line in require from `composer.json` and then run `update`

```
composer update
```

After removed, recommend to run below two command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

We have come with a great solution. This solution is practically done in Laravel 6. If you want to remove any package from your Laravel Project then you can easily remove the package by following below steps:

**Step 1:** You must know the package name which you want to remove. If you don't know the complete package name then you can open your project folder and go to the *composer.json* file and check the name in the require array:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/passport": "^8.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
```

Suppose, here I am going to remove the "fideloper/proxy" package.

**Step 2**: Open a command prompt with your project root folder directory

[image]

**Step 3:** First of all, clear all cache by the following commands. Run the commands one by one.

```
php artisan cache:clear  
php artisan config:clear
```

**Step 4:** Now write the following command to remove the package. Here you need to change your package name instead of my example package.

```
composer remove fideloper/proxy
```

Now, wait for a few seconds while your package is removed.

Comment: or `composer remove laravel/telescope --dev` if it is dev package

Answer (score 3):

On Laravel 8.*, the following steps work for me:

1. Run command `composer remove package-name` on the terminal
2. Remove `Provider` and `aliases` from file *Config/app.php*
3. Remove the related file from the *Config* folder.

Remove it from your code where you used it.

Comment: I have been trying this but i continuously get an error : 
    ` In ProviderRepository.php line 208:  
       class xxxxxx not found`

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the package folder from the vendor folder (manual delete)
2. Remove it from file *composer.json* and '**composer.lock**' files (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to search)
3. Remove it from file *config/app.php* and file *bootstrap/cache/config.php* files
4. Run these commands:

   ```
   composer remove **your-package-name**
   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan config:clear
   ```

Comment: Please never recommend that anybody should edit the `composer.lock` manually. Calling `composer remove` is enough, as this removes the package from the vendor folder, and from both composer files

Answer (score 1):

To remove any package in your Laravel project you only need to execute the below command using Composer.

```
composer remove {packageName}
```

eg: `composer remove maatwebsite/excel`
In this command, we are removing `maatwebsite/excel` package.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few steps here:

1. Go to file *composer.json* and look for the package and how it is written over there.

- for example

> { "require": {
> "twig/twig": "^3.0" } }

I wish to remove *twig* 3.0

2. Now open cmd and run `composer remove vendor/your_package_name` as `composer remove twig/twig` will remove the package.
3. As a final step, run `composer update`. This will surely give you a massage of `nothing to install or update`, but this is important in case your packages have inter-dependencies.

Comment: When adding an answer to six year old question with an accepted answer and fifteen existing answers it is important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses.

Comment: The most important thing I faced is point No.3, which we often ignore as we usually get "nothing to install or update", I was unfortunate while uninstalling certain illuminate component as I had sentinel which uses illuminate capsule. however thankfully update composer command helped here. the answers above misses on the inter-dependencies part, in case you feel its not important juss reply back I will remove my answer.

Comment: Calling `composer update` is not needed if you just want to remove a package