# Error while adding column in existing table

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

Im working in laravel 5.3, i want to add column in existing table (i.e., course_chapters). so that i have created migration file by the command

```
 php artisan make:migration add_description_to_course_chapters_table --table=course_chapters
```

Migration file was created and i have added some code to add column in that table as below

```
<?php
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
   class AddDescriptionToCourseChaptersTable extends Migration {
       public function up() {
           Schema::table('course_chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->text('description')->after('title');
           });
       }
       public function down(){
           Schema::table('course_chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->dropColumn('description');
           });
       }
   }
```

After i run command

`php artisan migrate`

the table was not created instead of that i got error

```
←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have  an error i  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m   version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set    utf 8 col  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  late utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL: create table     `course_chapters` () def  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  ault character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m

←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have   an error i  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MariaDB server  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m   version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set   utf 8 col  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  late utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1


←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  [PDOException]
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have   an error i  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     MariaDB server  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m   version for the right syntax to use near ') default character set    utf 8 col  ←[39;49m
←[37;41m  late utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1
   ←[39;49m
←[37;41m
   ←[39;49m
```

Any answer?

My existing table migration file is

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CourseChapters extends Migration
{
    /**
    * Run the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('course_chapters', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->integer('course_id');
           $table->integer('chapter_id');
           $table->string('title', 80);
           $table->string('source');
           $table->string('source_type');
           $table->string('max_attempts');
           $table->tinyInteger('status');
           $table->timestamps();
       });
    }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('course_chapters');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please add the error you got in the post. So that we can help you faster.

Comment: i have edited my post @AbhilekhSingh

Comment: can u attach the migration file or schema of the existing table?

Comment: i have attached existing migration file in my post @AdityaSingh

Comment: `the table was not created` but also said your table is created and you want to add new column right ?

Comment: yes i just want to add 1 column in existing table, But the course_chapters table is created already

Comment: Are you sure your existing migration to create `course_chapters` is not running ? can try with removing that file ?

Comment: Its running i simply added that code for reference.. add column migration is not running course_chapters table is available in db i have created it already

Comment: before running add column migrate i was installed dbal/doctrine package is that a problem

Comment: Are you using mariadb? not mysql? right?

Comment: im using mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it well.

To modify/add column in existing database you must install `doctrine/dbal`, as you already have. But if you look at `->after()` method, you will see that it's only working in `MySQL` database. Please look at this section in [Laravel 5.3 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#column-modifiers)

I think your problem is that you are using **MariaDB**.

Comment: so what should i do for this

Comment: Don't use `->after()` method at all.

Comment: Instead of after() what can be used

Comment: Nothing, don't use it at all and your column will be added in the end of table.

Comment: i think the problem is because of dbal/doctorine package could you please tell me the command to revert back the package installed

Comment: Follow this [instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135356/discussion-between-vinothini-and-zgabievi).