# Remove a package from laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4

I installed this Cartalyst Stripe package for laravel which was nothing but trouble for me.. I just couldn't get it working and now I decided to remove it completely. 
So, I remove the line that requires this package in composer.json.
I removed the line from confing/app.php from the providers & aliases array. I also removed all references of that Cartalyst package from my code..
Somehow, after I run composer update I still get this error..

```
  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Class 'Cartalyst\Stripe\Laravel\StripeServiceProvider' not found


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: check following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer

Comment: That's exactly what I did.. still the same error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear config cache. Run `php artisan config:clear` command to fix this.

If you still see the error message when you run the artisan commands, clear the `bootstrap/cache` directory manually.

Comment: I tried php artisan config:clear but when I run this, I'm getting the same error..

Comment: In this case, make full-text search for `StripeServiceProvider` on your project. If nothing found, delete cache manually. Go to `bootstrap/cache` directory and delete `services.php` file.

Comment: Your answer helped me.. The problem was indeed in the cache directory.. In config.php, I noticed that I added some lines by mistake..