# Dependency has been removed but class error exists in Artisan

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am working on blocktrail-api where I have created a service provider to access the blocktrail-api object, but the dependency didn't work so I removed service provider and everything related to that package but the error still persist even after doing `php artisan`.

[image: Red box shows error message which I can see]

Here is the laravel error log

```
[2017-06-02 19:06:57] local.ERROR: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException: Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $apiKey ]] in class Blocktrail\SDK\BlocktrailSDK in /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:888
Stack trace:
#0 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(826): Illuminate\Container\Container->unresolvablePrimitive(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#1 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(779): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolvePrimitive(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#2 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(746): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#3 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(598): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Blocktrail\\SDK\\...')
#4 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(567): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Blocktrail\\SDK\\...')
#5 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Blocktrail\\SDK\\...')
#6 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(840): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Blocktrail\\SDK\\...')
#7 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(780): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
#8 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(746): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveDependencies(Array)
#9 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(598): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Console\\Com...')
#10 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(567): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Console\\Com...')
#11 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(708): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\\Console\\Com...')
#12 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(192): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\\Console\\Com...')
#13 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(206): Illuminate\Console\Application->resolve('App\\Console\\Com...')
#14 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(285): Illuminate\Console\Application->resolveCommands(Array)
#15 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->getArtisan()
#16 /home/amit/Projects/mlm/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 {main}
```

Comment: please double check did you remove service provider from config/app.php, and if yes can you give us a part of log from storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Yeah i have removed it from config/app.php. I am adding a log here

Comment: Did you try `composer dumpautoload` as well?

Comment: Yes i did that also

Comment: Can you manually delete cache/compiled.php

Comment: Try `php artisan clear-compiled` and then `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: Still same error

Comment: One more doublecheck: Did your application use console commands if yes did you delete that command from app/Console/Kernel.php

Comment: Exactly that was the reason...I was using console command where i was injecting that class as a parameter Thanks Mamikon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out, it was that: Amit used console command where He was injecting that class as a parameter, and after removing it from app/Console/Kernel.php problem was solved.

If this doesn't help you, you can look through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer), did you do everything right or not.