# Remove package from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, package

I executed these 2 commands:

```
composer require realrashid/sweet-alert
composer require infinety/alerts *@dev
```

They are packages to use SweetAlert on Laravel but they are not working and I found a better one, I want to remove them, when I do `composer remove vendor/realrashid` or `composer remove vendor/infinety` it say that the package is not installed and is not required in my composer.json, so It has not been removed but the package is still here..

Comment: Remove the `vendor` folder and run `composer install` should fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a package from Laravel using composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer)

Answer (score 11):

No need to use `vendor`. Just `composer remove realrashid/sweet-alert`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to go to your `composer.json` file and then remove that certain package then recall the '`composer update`' method. Since `composer remove`  will completely remove the library to your composer cache because you might using that library to other projects so when you try to composer install again that library, composer will download that package again instead of checking the composer cache memory.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run this command in your terminal:   composer remove vendor/package_name

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).