# How to remove ckeditor package (error: Class 'Ckeditor\CkeditorServiceProvider' not found)?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I followed the steps mentioned here:

[How to remove a package from Laravel using composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer)

including the step: Remove Service Provider from "app/config/app.php" (reference in "providers" array)

However, since I got an error:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Ckeditor\CkeditorServiceProvider' not found  

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

The app is down and I cannot do any operation in terminal. How to get rid of the reference to this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then run these commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload -o
```

If an error occurs while clearing cache, then delete cache files under `bootstrap/cache` manually.

Comment: I get an error _'Class Ckeditor\CkeditorServiceProvider' not found_ when I try  to run any command.

Comment: @aabk did you remove ckeditor lines from composer.json and composer.lock

Comment: Yes, they are not present in both files.

Comment: @aabk can you delete files under bootstrap/cache folder manually ?

Comment: This helped! Thank you very much.

Comment: @abbk i deleted all files under  bootstrap/cache but now getting a lot of errors  routes/web.php:266
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::routes([])

      +4 vendor frames 
  6   app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:56

Comment: @Jeche can you open a new question with all details ? let me know when you open the question, I would like to help