# Why Deleted migration in laravel app migrate when using migrate:fresh or others

Tags: laravel, migration

CMD commad result:

```
PS D:\WampDatabase\www\PakistanBloodDonors> php artisan migrate                                                         Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.37 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.26 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_09_22_192348_create_messages_table
Migrated:  2019_09_22_192348_create_messages_table (0.31 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_16_211433_create_favorites_table
Migrated:  2019_10_16_211433_create_favorites_table (0.19 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_18_223259_add_avatar_to_users
Migrated:  2019_10_18_223259_add_avatar_to_users (0 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_20_211056_add_messenger_color_to_users
Migrated:  2019_10_20_211056_add_messenger_color_to_users (0.19 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_22_000539_add_dark_mode_to_users
Migrated:  2019_10_22_000539_add_dark_mode_to_users (0.14 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_10_25_214038_add_active_status_to_users
Migrated:  2019_10_25_214038_add_active_status_to_users (0.28 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_03_25_130425_create_admins_table
Migrated:  2020_03_25_130425_create_admins_table (0.28 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_04_24_043508_create_opinions_table
Migrated:  2020_04_24_043508_create_opinions_table (0.12 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_04_27_034017_create_volunteers_table
Migrated:  2020_04_27_034017_create_volunteers_table (0.1 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_04_27_145232_create_contacts_table
Migrated:  2020_04_27_145232_create_contacts_table (0.08 seconds)
```

Problem is that i have only users_table ,admins_table , volunteers_table , opinions_table, and contact_table in laravel migration folder.. but when i use command `php artisan migrate:fresh`then its create all migrations above in which messages_table, favorites_table and others table included automatically ..i don't know where from these are coming and migrates...

why this problem create basically i was using chatify realtime chating package in laravel app all above messages favorites avatars tables are part of that package but i have remove every file and folder from laravel app ...then why these migration are now creating? anyone can help me who knows?

Answer (score 0):

will as you mentioned it is chatify migrations and the reason for that is that you didn't remove all the files correctly you should look in your vendors or other places and you will find chatify folder then delete it

as you can see here in the package repo

https://github.com/munafio/chatify

you will find database enter it you will find migrations and its just like the tables that had been created by your app

and here you can find a question about how to remove packages correctly it might be good to take a look at

[How to remove a package from Laravel using composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-to-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-composer)