# How to completely Uninstall chatify from laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

am using laravel and i have installed chatify in my project, now i want to remove it from the project completely. I have tried removing it`s migrations, models and view files as well as chatify config file.

I will appreciate any help THANKS!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23126562/how-can-i-remove-a-package-from-laravel-using-php-composer

Answer (score 0):

Try to run
php remove munifo/chatify

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).