# Would reset hard uninstall a package?

Tags: php, laravel, git

Would reset hard uninstall a package?

Say I have commits

789f658a6e55a65cc3f056asf – Commit before installing package
789fdfdsfse55a65cc3f056asf – Commit after installing package

If I reset to “Commit before installing package” would that uninstall the package or just remove the line in composer json?

What is the right way of uninstalling the package?

When I reset hard it looks the package is still not uninstalled though I could no longer see it in composer.json

Comment: That depends if you have vendor in git or not. You should share in your question which files you commit: composer.json, composer.lock, vendor directory. Add that via [edit].

Comment: _"What is the right way of uninstalling the package?"_ - does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/23126562/367456 (it does not necessarily answer the git part, that Q&A is about Laravel + Composer)

Comment: The `vendor` folder should not be included in `git` (in a Laravel project, the default `.gitignore` file that comes with it includes `/vendor`). Rolling back a commit will affect your `composer` files, which in turn will affect your `vendor` folder when running `composer install`, so yes, a hard reset will uninstall a package, assuming you follow up the reset with a `composer install`.

Answer (score 3):

Git itself knows nothing about Composer, or even PHP. What gets rolled back when you checkout a commit, reset, etc, depends entirely on what files you commit.

In Composer, there are three places where a package ends up:

- Listed in `composer.json`. This is the file you edit by hand. It tells Composer what packages you depend on, and what the minimum and maximum versions it's allowed to use, but *not* the specific version installed.
- Listed in `composer.lock`. This is the file that *Composer generates* when you run `composer update` (and some other commands). It lists *exact* versions of every package installed, including indirect dependencies (packages needed by other packages, rather than listed directly in your `composer.json`).
- Actually installed in the `vendor` directory. These are the files PHP will actually execute.

As [the Composer documentation explains](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies) for a standalone project, you should normally **commit both composer.json and composer.lock, but not `vendor`**. This allows you to install *the exact same versions* each time you switch branch, deploy to a new server, etc, by running `composer install`.

If this is what you've done, then by resetting to or checking out the commit before you updated the package, you will get your old `composer.lock`, but git won't touch your `vendor` directory.

To actually *install* the packages listed in that `composer.lock`, you would run `composer install`. That will make the content of your `vendor` directory match the exact versions listed in `composer.lock`, including uninstalling things which aren't listed there.

Answer (score 0):

**The easy way:**

you can remove any package from your project by run this command (if you use composer):

```
composer remove <package_name>
```

**The complex way:**

remove the package lines from **composer.json**

remove the package from **config/bundles.php**

run `composer install`